# Using an xp:checkBoxGroup and trying to put a simple box border around all the values

Tags: css, xpages

It seems the only option available today is border=x where x is the thickness of the border.  It looks really ugly as it outlines each choice in the group.

I want a simple border around all the choices.  When I go into debug it I can manually add fram="box" to the generated Table html and it looks great.

I can't figure out how to add frame="box" to the xp:checkBoxGroup  I've tried using attributes without success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `xp:checkBoxGroup` the XPages runtime puts the checkboxes in table cells and wraps it with a `fieldset` element. You can easily target that using some CSS. That's how I would solve this.

If you want a simple border around your checkbox group you can do this:

```
<style>
    fieldset.xspCheckBox {
        border: 1px solid #333333;
    }
</style>

<xp:checkBoxGroup id="checkBoxGroup1">
    <xp:selectItem
        itemLabel="Blue"
        itemValue="blue">
    </xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem
        itemLabel="Green"
        itemValue="green">
    </xp:selectItem>
</xp:checkBoxGroup>
```

Or if you want a border around every option you can use this:

```
<style>
    fieldset.xspCheckBox {
        border: 0;
    }
    fieldset.xspCheckBox label {
        border: 1px solid #444444;
        padding: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    fieldset.xspCheckBox label:hover {
        background: #eeeeee;
    }
</style>
```

(note that the `:hover` class isn't really necessary, but adds a hover effect to all options: depending on your browser requirements that might not be supported)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a style with a border definition to your xp:checkBoxGroup:

```
<xp:checkBoxGroup id="..." value="..." style="border:1px solid black;">
    ...
</xp:checkBoxGroup>
```

Instead of putting the style directly into xp:checkBoxGroup definition you can use a css class.